# how to get refresh token in msal-browser Azure AD B2C login?

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, refresh-token, msal-react

we have used msal-browser for Azure AD B2C login in the react application with vite & RTK.
We want to refresh the token once the main access token expires.

But inside the react application, we couldn't receive a refresh token by calling any method of @azure/msal-browser.

By calling the acquireTokenSilent method, we got an access token but didn't receive a refresh token.

We want a refresh token inside our react application code, which we can able to see in the API response.
But as mentioned, this API is called by @azure/msal-browser internally and we didn't get a refresh token on the react code side.

[Reference API response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOjty.png)

Implemented Code for acquiring the silent token

```
if (event.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS || event.eventType === EventType.ACQUIRE_TOKEN_SUCCESS) {
  if (event?.payload) {
    if (event?.payload?.idToken) {
      instance
        .acquireTokenSilent({
          scopes: [AuthConfig.Policy],
          account: currentAccount
        })
        .then(async (response) => {
          // Application level logic here
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your code in the question as a text formate not in an image?

Comment: @DasariKamali code added in the question itself